# Is there a simple way to capture inbound emails on Heroku and forward them to another mailbox?

Tags: python, django, email, heroku

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer to this. Let's say I have a list of email addresses, for example:

```
[
"contact@example.com",
"jobs@example.com",
"support@example.com",
"investors@example.com"
]
```

and I want to forward all incoming mail to those addresses to one email account hosted elsewhere (e.g. `personal_account@gmail.com`). I'm running a Django server on Heroku.

So far every third-party API I looked at (Mandrill, Postmark, etc.) parses the incoming emails and outputs a JSON, but it assumes your output needs to be POSTed somewhere on a websocket. Is there a simple way to forward the entire content (attachments, fancy HTML body, and all) to a different email account without using a websocket? If necessary I want to avoid the pain of parsing the JSON output of a third-party API and forwarding it with smtplib. This seems like something that *should* be easy to implement, but I can't figure out how.

Also this is probably a newbie question: do I put this code in `views.py`? It should be initiated upon receipt of an email, and not on initiation of some user action on the web app interface itself (e.g. submitting a form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not currently have built-in facilities for apps to receive emails. Heroku does have several add-ons that let you do this, including [CloudMailin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudmailin) and [MailGun](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mailgun).